# How to sort a list in alphabetic order and pick certain range of characters from Entity Framework list?

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, list, entity-framework-5

I have a list of records. And i want to pick subset of list with respect to their starting character.
The list contains elements and i want to pick elements of certain range from it. For example a list has records with their starting characters, A - Z, i want to pick records A-J, how can i do it in entity framework list. I dont want to use LINQ but i want to use entity functions.

For example

```
ObjectSet.Where(p=>p.Name starts with A and J)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
from c in Contacts
where "ABCDEFGHIJKL".Contains(c.LastName.Substring(0, 1))
select c
```

it will issue sql like

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
WHERE ( 
        CAST(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING([Extent1].[LastName], 0 + 1, 1), N'ABCDEFGHIJKL') AS int)
    ) > 0
```